# Change pointer value after function block

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, access-violation

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void copyString(char *input, int offset, int length, bool invert, char *output, int output_offset)
{
char *cp = new char[length+1];
for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++)
{
    cp[i] = input[offset + i];
}
if (invert)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
    {
        swap(cp[i], cp[length - i - 1]);
    }
}
int count = 0;
while (output[count])
    count++;
int cutlength = count - output_offset;
char *temp = new char[count + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++)
    temp[i] = output[i];
for (int i = 0; i < cutlength; i++)
{
    temp[output_offset + i] = cp[i];
}
output = temp;
}

void main()
{
char *st = "Hello world";
cout << "st= " << st << endl;
char *st2 = "My name is C++";
cout << "st2= " << st2 << endl;
copyString(st, 6, 5, true, st2, 11);
cout << "st2 output= " << st2 << endl;
system("Pause");
}
```

The idea is that the function will copy a length of an input string and replace a part of an output with that copied string.

All i want to do is make the **st2 value change after copyString function**, but i can't seem to change it through **temp** var. But if i try to change the **st2** value in the function, i got the Access Violation Error. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your program, executing it one line at a time, and examining the values of all variables after each step, what observations did you make regarding the reason why your program is crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

st and st2 are pointers to a constant string, and as such you shouldn't try to change there contents (although you can make them point at an entirely different string).

To make st2 a character array (string) that is editable, you should declare st2 as follows

```
char st2[] = "My name is C++";
```

In your copyString function, the output pointer originally points at the same place as st2, and then at the end of the function make output point at a different string. However this wont change st2 or its contents in any way.

You need either need to make st2 a character array and edit this array in the copyString function, or have the copyString function create and return a new string that st2 can point at (although likely to end up with memory leaks if your not careful).

The following should do what you are after. It can could be improved a little by removing cp altogether and directly writing from the input buffer to output buffer.

```
void copyString(char *input, int offset, int length, bool invert, char *output, int output_offset)
{
    char *cp = new char[length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++)
    {
        cp[i] = input[offset + i];
    }
    if (invert)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
        {
            swap(cp[i], cp[length - i - 1]);
        }
    }
    int count = strlen(output);
    int cutlength = count - output_offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < cutlength; i++)
    {
        output[output_offset + i] = cp[i];
    }
    delete[] cp;
}

void main()
{
    char st[] = "Hello world";
    cout << "st= " << st << endl;
    char st2[] = "My name is C++";
    cout << "st2= " << st2 << endl;
    copyString(st, 6, 5, true, st2, 11);
    cout << "st2 output= " << st2 << endl;
    system("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `copyString` function is generally similar to the C `strcpy` function (if not to take the inversion option into the account). It needs the output to be an already allocated buffer (a `char` array) of a sufficient size to write the string content into (say, you may allocate a buffer using `new char[strlen(str) + 1]` ) . However, you are trying to write into the memory where the string constants `"Hello world"` and `"My name is C++"` are located. This is obviously a memory access violation (otherwise you would modify those constants).

No need to say that this way of dealing with strings is extremely error prone and far not C++ish.

Answer (score 0):

1) You count the `output` length (undefined behavior!), not the `input` one.

2) `output` pointer goes to nowhere - do you want to use a reference function argument for it?

Comment: the output one is the one that i want to have the change. 

Example: st = "Hello world" ,st2 = "My name is C++", copyString(st, 6, 5, true, st2, 11) => st2 = "My name is dlr". That's why i want to modify the output, or point the output to another value (temp), but both seems not working

Comment: Do you mean changing the pointer or changing the pointed content? If the second, you will have a violation if you provide a pointer to a string constant. If the first, it should be treated as an output only, and counting its pointed content length makes no sense.

Comment: (In my answer I've assumed that the first choice takes place)

Answer (score 0):

Memory access violation is due to your are trying to modify a string, which size can't accommodate extra length (i.e. st2 in your case)

Note: Temp method worked without error as your updated the base address of st2 <-- temp.

Also boundary checking against offset & *input params* lengths are also recommended.
In general use of **strcpy_s** is preferred over **strcpy**.